# Error with IP and Nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, dns, reverse-proxy, dyndns

I configured my Nginx as simple reverse proxy.

I'm just using basic setting

```
location / {
    proxy_pass foo.dnsalias.net;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header P3P;
}
```

The problem is that after some time (few days) the site behind nginx become unaccessible. Indead nginx try to call a bad ip (the site behind nginx is at my home behind my box and I'm a using a dyn-dns because my ip is not fixe). This dyn-dns is always valid (I can call my site directly) but for obscure reason Nginx get stuck with that..

So as said, nginx just give me 504 Gateway Time-out after some time. It looks like the error come when my ip change at home.
Here is a sample of error log:

```
[error] ... upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: my.current.ip, server: myreverse.server.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://my.old
.home.ip", host: "myreverse.server.com"
```

So do you know why nginx is using ip instead of the DN ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If the `proxy_pass` value doesn't contain variables, nginx will resolve domain names to IPs while loading the configuration and cache them until you restart/reload it. This is quite understandable from a performance point of view.

But, in case of dynamic DNS record change, this may not be desired. So two options are available depending on the license you possess or not.

## Commercial version (Nginx+)

In this case, use an upstream block and specify which domain name need to be resolved periodically using a specific resolver. Records TTL can be overriden using `valid=time` parameter. The `resolve` parameter of the `server` directive will force the DN to be resolved periodically.

```
http {    

    resolver X.X.X.X valid=5s;

    upstream dynamic {
        server foo.dnsalias.net resolve;
    }

    server {

        server_name www.example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://dynamic;
            ...
        }

    }

}
```

This feature was added in Nginx+ 1.5.12.

## Community version (Nginx)

In that case, you will also need a custom resolver as in the previous solution. But to workaround the unavailable upstream solution, you need to use a variable in your `proxy_pass` directive. That way nginx will use the resolver too, honoring the caching time specified with the `valid` parameter. For instance, you can use the domain name as a variable :

```
http {  

    resolver X.X.X.X valid=5s;

    server {

        server_name www.example.com;
        set $dn "foo.dnsalias.net"; 

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://$dn;
            ...
        }

    }

}
```

Then, you will likely need to add a `proxy_redirect` directive to handle redirects.

Comment: Sounds good, I will try this solution ang give feedback then. Thanks a lot. (community version)

Comment: I tried to use several resolver but nothing works, I always get `recv() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: X.X.X.X:53` with X as different ip adress I tried.

Comment: (too late edit) What exactly should I put in resolver ?

Comment: @max54 That's an other issue there. It means nothing is listening at X.X.X.X:53 or that a firewall is blocking you from accessing it. What's the output of `dig foo.dnsalias.net @X.X.X.X` ? You should set in this directive a list of DNS such as the ones in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Xavier Lucas after some time it seems that it doesn't work, my ip still is the wrong after it changed. I followed your second instrcutions about non commercial version. Still need any help :/

Comment: @max54 I'm using this setup myself and it **works** so this is coming from something else in your machine/network and this is no more in the scope of the orignal question. Run tcpdump to convince yourself of DNS requests getting issued every `valid` period. Thus that's not really appropriate to unaccept answers like you do, without even trying to figure what's wrong on the rest of your plateform.

Comment: You are right, my apologies. I will take another look to my whole configuration :)

Comment: this is a good solution, but keep in mind it might break your proxy_redirect if you're relying on the [default behaviour](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe check this out http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,215830,215832#msg-215832

```
resolver 127.0.0.1;
set $backend "foo.example.com";
proxy_pass http://$backend;

In such setup ip address of "foo.example.com" will be looked up
dynamically and result will be cached for 5 minutes.
```

Comment: This can be improved by adding $request_uri to the end of your $backend line.  set $backend "foo.example.com/$request_uri";