# How to get nginx host variable to work with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I am trying to setup an nginx proxy in front of any s3 website that I point at it. In the example below I have my DNS records customsite.com pointing to my proxy. When I don't use any variable for the destination of the proxy_pass there isn't an issue, but I want to be able to just dynamically pass the request using $host. **How do I get the $host variable to behave with proxy_pass?**

**This Works**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    add_header RequestedHost $host; # The host is returned as expected (customsite.com)
    # go get it from s3
    proxy_pass http://customsite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com;
  }
}
```

**This Doesn't Work**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    add_header RequestedHost $host;
    # go get it from s3
    proxy_pass http://$host.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com; # Doesn't resolve
  }
}
```

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/26957754 you can also try *proxy_pass http://s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/$host*