# Nginx dns resolver refresh - Openshift (Kubernetes)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, openshift

I have an Ngins, deployed as a pod inside the Openshift cluster, acts as reverse proxy for a backend-service. The backend-service has Kubernetes service to loadbalance the traffic between the pods (we use ha proxy as loadbalancer). The Nginx `pass_proxy` all the request to the service.

```
location /service-1/api {
  proxy_pass http://service-svc/api;
}
```

Anytime the Kubernetes service is recreated or it get a new IP address, the Nginx doesnt refresh the new address - this throws 504 timeout error. I tried the `resolver` of the Nginx with `127.0.0.1`, `127.0.0.11` and other ways to force the Nginx refresh the dns lookup, along with assigning the service to a variable.

However, this doesn't solve the problem. The Nginx couldn't resolve the service, saying it cannot resolve using `127.0.0.1:53`. What is the right way to put the resolver? What IP should I provide in the resolver?

Comment: You don't need to configure `resolver` if nginx is deployed as a pod inside the Openshift cluster. In `proxy_pass`, use `service name` instead of `service ip`. If it doesn't work, check if this `service name` is wrong, or if internal DNS Server fails. This link may help. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/

Comment: As you can see in my question, I am using the service name only, not its IP address. Still when the service gets new IP the Nginx still calls the old one - I found this from Nginx logs.

Comment: possible duplicate [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/240476/how-to-force-nginx-to-resolve-dns-of-a-dynamic-hostname-everytime-when-doing-p) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956979/error-with-ip-and-nginx-as-reverse-proxy)

Comment: It might help to check pod's dnspolicy. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-policy